# how can i check class constructor count exactly?

Tags: c++, class

I'm constructing a new CLASS that contain CLASS create-count. Is there another exception in my code, check create-count?

I want to know remain class `A`'s counts.

So, I create class A contain `createCount` that increase or decrease when constructor or destructor called.

```cpp
class A { 
    public :
        static int createCount;
        int m;

        A(int m = 0) : m(m) {
            createCount++;
        }

        ~A() {
            createCount--;
        }
};
int A::createCount = 0;
```

I think upper code has no problem, but when i use `vector`, createCount change unexpected.

```
int main() {
    vector<A> aVector;
    aVector.push_back( A(1) ); // expected 1, real 0
    aVector.push_back( A(2) ); // expected 2, real -1
    aVector.push_back( A(3) ); // expected 3, real -3
}
```

My Answer for upper code is like under.

```cpp
// for this answer, i search with "rules of ...(zero, five, ..)"
class A {
    /* same like upper */
    A(const A& other) {
        createCount++;
    }
};
```

But I'm not sure there's another exception or some problem with my answer.

I want to know upper code has same problem still.

Thank you for read my question.

Comment: Why do you need to know the count of the class?  If you got this to compile successfully, what would be the purpose?  If you change compiler options or compilers, you will get different results with this "count".  This is getting close to an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You are forgetting to account for your defaulted copy/move constructor. Vector reallocation will move/copy a bunch of stuff around.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I used this code for practice `boost::shared_ptr`. I want to know when memory assign & free time, actually. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know upper code has same problem still.

The answer is precisely as you say: violating the Rule of Three / Five.  Without the copy constructor, `std::vector::push_back` will use a POD copy, which simply duplicates the data members in `A` but has no knowledge of the reference-counting side effect that you're looking for.

Going just a little deeper: when you call `aVector.push_back(A(1))`, first `A(1)` constructs a temporary instance of `A`.  Then `push_back` will either copy (or move) that value into the vector, and finally the temporary is destroyed.

Because you provide neither a copy- or move-constructor, the new copy of `A` that lives in the vector does not increase your count.  But when the temporary `A(1)` is destroyed, the count is still decreased.  Hence, each push operation results in a decrease of count.

I fixed your copy constructor, as it was wrong:

```
A(const A& other) : A(other.m) {}
```

And after adding a copy constructor, you will need to specify move constructor if it is required.  In this case, it's kinda trivial since no actual data must be moved so you can just use the `A(int)` constructor again.

```
A(A&& other) : A(other.m) {}
```

Of course, a move should actually neither increase or decrease count, but you have no logic for separating this in `A`.

Note also that your code is not thread-safe.  If you need it to be, then use a `std::atomic` for the count.

Comment: when you write *rvalue* you actually mean *temporary object*. An rvalue is an expression.